# Whatsapp contacts duplicating my contact list

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I created a small activity that displays all contacts with phone numbers in my phone. However, there are duplicates for contacts that have whatsapp installed. For example, if John is in my contact list and he has a whatsapp account as well, the list would look like this:

...

Jake

John

John

JP

...

This is my code for assigning the cursor to the the adapter which links to a listview.

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
    final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);

    String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

**EDIT**
With this code, I confirmed that the duplicates have 0 value for the **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE** which means it is a custom contact (Whatsapp). The rest are 2 which means it is a normal contact.

**I need to figure out a query where it doesn't use any contacts where ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE == 0**

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit late. However I was having the same issue.

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE as per the  [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html)  refers not to whether it is a custom contact but to what type of contact it is i.e. Mobile(2), Home(1) or Work(3). Whatsapp contacts will be a 2 - mobile.

I used the following function to remove the duplicates (not sure if there is a better way):

```
private boolean checkDuplicate(String position) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map;
    Integer testNull;

    map=new LinkedHashMap<>();

    testNull=map.get(position);
    if(testNull==null) {
        testNull=1;
        map.put(position, testNull);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        testNull=testNull+1;
        if(testNull==2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            map.put(position, testNull);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```